# Finding Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters returns 0 for a string

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find the [Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/). For Example

```
Input: s = "abcabcbb"
Output: 3
Explanation: The answer is "abc", with the length of 3.
```

**My code:**

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        l=[]
        c=0
        for i in s:
            if (i not in l):
                l.append(i)
            else:
                if(len(l)>c):
                    c=len(l)
                    l=[]
                    l.append(i)
        return c
```

My question is  when I pass this string (" "), it is returing 0 instead of 1. Why is this coming as 0?

Comment: For a string length of 1, the `else` block never hits because `i not in l` will always be true, so `c=len(l)` will never get a chance to run and change the return value from 0. I'd rethink your approach here -- if `l` never drops elements and monotonically grows, I don't see how that can produce a correct answer. Maybe think in terms of sliding windows.

Comment: Got it Thanks will implment

Answer (score 0):

How about if you set your default value of c to 1, i.e. `c=1`

#### Edit-01:

add an additional `if` condition:

```py
if (len(s) == 0):
    return 0
```

Comment: I cannot do that if a string is empty "" it should return 0

Comment: if string s="" it should return 0
if String s=" " it should return 1